# uiscrollview for scrolling a very, very tall page

Tags: uitextview

From top to bottom I have UIView, UIScrollView, a UIImage, a UILabel, a UITextView and a UIButton.

My reason behind the top-most UIScrollView was so the whole vertical content would scroll.

What I really need a substitute for is the UITextView (5th down) because the UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView.  And this substitute must accomodate the very tall column of formatted text.

What I don't want is a scrollable object in the middle of the page; I want the whole page to be scrollable.

One more thing ... please note there's a button immediately below this tall column of text.

John Love

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THANK YOU! Ashack and Pentagp.  I guess I finally had to surrender and dump the idea that IB could be used for all GUI ...

The entire UIView contains a UILabel, a UIImage, a UITextView and
a UIButton at the very bottom.

The goal here was to make this entire content scrollable.

Thanks to you guys at stackoverflow.com:

> 1. using IB, un-check "Scrolling Enabled" for the UITextView
>      because it's a concrete type of UIScrollView
> 2. using IB, drag a UIScrollView to the UIView and match sizes    and
>      insure that the UIScrollView encloses all sub-views
> 3. make the UITextView height = its contentSize.height
> 4. move the UIButton to below this UITextView

and then, thanks to iphonedevsdk.com:

> 1. adjust the contentSize.height of the top-most UIScrollview    to
>      include the height of the re-positioned UIButton

**Problem solved!!!**

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific, but I think you're asking how to make a text view that does not scroll, and expands to fit the text. You can do this with UILabel, but it's a multi-step process. The same will work for UITextView if you disable scrolling and set the contentSize to match the frame dimensions.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100,100,100,100)]; 
label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
NSString *yourTextString = @"your text";
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(100, 500);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourTextString sizeWithFont:label.font 
                    constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize 
                    lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];
CGRect labelFrame = label.frame;
labelFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
labelFrame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
label.frame = labelFrame;
```

Then from there, use the label's frame to set the position of the button and all elements below it.

Comment: I am working with a Tab Controller App, with 10 distinct UIViewControllers.  All 10 have one superview which supplies the instance methods for everything based on the tag ID I've set within IB for each of the 10.  My ultimate goal is to make a super-long scrollable UIView (with images, text and a button)for each UIViewController and the content of that UIView to be set within IB.  I may not be able to avoid it, but I'd like to shy away from setting each UIView's content programmatically

Comment: Well, if you are trying to achieve that sort of liquid layout, you will need to do it programmatically unless you can use a UIWebView and HTML/CSS for your content. I'm afraid you'll have to use my answer and adjust layouts programmatically using the method I describe above, starting at the first element that has a variable height.

Comment: Just had another idea (based on another reader of StackOverflow ... what about embedding a styled text file in the project and load that into the UIView ... could do all that in one place, namely, my super-view viewDidLoad because my UIView's -viewDidLoad just does one thing before it calls my super-view's -viewDidLoad and that one thing is to assign a unique viewControllerID in the form of a NSString*

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you don't want nested scroll.
So set yourTextView.scrollEnabled = NO; //Do it programmatically our in the nib

Also in order to display all the text set yourTextView frame height to its content height:

```
    yourTextView.frame = CGRectMake(yourTextView.frame.origin.x, 
                                    yourTextView.frame.origin.y,
                                    yourTextView.frame.size.width,
                                    yourTextView.contentSize.height + (yourTextView.contentSize.width > yourTextView.frame.size.width ? (yourTextView.contentSize.width * yourTextView.contentSize.height / (yourTextView.contentSize.width - yourTextView.frame.size.width)) - yourTextView.contentSize.height :0)));

/*
If textView is dynamically filled, you have to check if yourTextView.contentSize.width is bigger than yourTextView.frame.size.width then add proportionally what is remaining to the height. 
*/
```

At the end change your button position if needed:

```
yourbutton.frame = CGRectMake(yourbutton.frame.origin.x, 
                                yourTextView.frame.origin.y + yourTextView.frame.size.height + 20, //If you want your button to be 20 point after your textView
                                yourbutton.frame.size.width,
                                yourbutton.frame.size.height);
```

Hope that will help you...

Comment: I am working with a Tab Controller App, with 10 distinct UIViewControllers.  All 10 have one superview which supplies the instance methods for everything based on the button's tag ID I've set within IB for each of the 10.  My ultimate goal is to make a super-long scrollable UIView (with images, text and a button)for each UIViewController and the content of that UIView to be set within IB.  I may not be able to avoid it, but I'd like to shy away from setting each UIView's content programmatically

Comment: Couldn't your superview have a method that manage the layout: expand subviews that are UITextView and translate subviews positioned after.
When your view controller viewDidLoad is called, call the layoutManagement method.

Comment: Just had another idea ... what about embedding a styled text file in the project and load that into the UIView ... could do all that in one place, namely, my super-view viewDidLoad because my UIView's -viewDidLoad just does one thing before it calls my super-view's -viewDidLoad and that one thing is to assign a unique viewControllerID in the form of a NSString*